# Question about a matrix in a problem of differential equations

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

I am studyng differential equations from a book called linear ordinary differential equation by Earl A. Coddington this is the problem

Consider the nonhomogeneous system 
\begin{equation}\label{equation:1}
X'=A(t)X+B(t),  \  A\in C(I,M_n(\mathcal F)), \ B \in C(I, \mathcal F^n  )\ 
\end{equation}

on some interval $I$, together with the corresponding homogeneous system
\begin{equation}
X'=A(t)X
\end{equation}
For $t,\tau \in I$. let $S(t, r) \in M_n(\mathcal F)$ be the unique matrix satisfying
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial S}{\partial t}(t,\tau)=A(t)S(t,\tau), \ S(\tau,\tau)=I_n. 
\end{equation}show that

1. if $X$ is any basis for $X'=A(t)X$ then
   \begin{equation}
   S(t,\tau)=X(t)X^{-1}(\tau), \ t,\tau \in I 
   \end{equation}
2. $S(t,\tau)S(\tau,\sigma)=S(t,\sigma), \ t,\tau,\sigma \in I$

I'm confused that the matrix has two evaluations $S(t,\tau)$ I don't see what it means and the book dont have examples about this.

Comment: What are you confused about precisely? To put it simply, $S$ has two variables, meaning for any $t,\sigma \in I$ you have a matrix $S(t, \sigma)$. Maybe you're confused about how to interpret $S$ physically?